# .ics files provided on a URL for synchronization

Tags: calendar, caldav

The ERP I am working with can be configured to regularly export scheduled events for each user to an .ics file. In order for the updates to appear in the calendar client of the user, they need to re-import their personal .ics after it has been modified by the ERP with the new events.

Having to manually re-import the calendar file several times a day is a hassle for our users and I'd like to somehow make their individual calendars available on a URL to benefit from synchronization, sharing features, etc. Here is an example of how I'd like the users to subscribe to my calendar on the [macOS calendar app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRWcF.png).

This way, my ERP would be overwriting the .ics file several times per day and each modification to the .ics file would automatically be visible inside any calendar client that has successfully subscribed to the calendar's URL (with authentication to protect the access of each calendar).

I tried Baikal and sabre/dav, but both these options don't work for me as I don't have a way of importing .ics files into the server's database (SQLite or MySQL).

I also tried Radicale, which stores the calendars directly as .ics files, but it doesn't seem to have authentication when adding the calendar into the client or calendar sharing features, which is something I need. I also don't see how I'd make the server aware of modifications made to the calendar file by the ERP.

Are there any ways for me to implement this?

Thanks